# Selecting data.frame rows using a vector of factors

Tags: r, dataframe, row

I have a dataframe like this:

```
> df
#                   1    2    3     4    5    6    7    8     9   10
# ENSG00000000003 2407 2345 1052  2191 2542  812 3595 4215  1100 5457
# ENSG00000000005    0    5    0     0    1    0    1    0    12    0
# ENSG00000000419 1843 1528 1520  1789 1144 1946 2017 2794  1455 2258
# ENSG00000000457  611  536  496   637  621  687  966  774   822 3026
# ENSG00000000460  453  493  884  1180  338  541  606  650   520 3479
# ENSG00000000938  249  296  995   113 1073  233  333 4441  2708  404
# ENSG00000000971 3570 1126 2431  1395 6452 7677 8222 1188 20762 4111
# ENSG00000001036 3774 1573 3323  1958 2029 2022 4236 1641  4195 1313
```

and want to select the following genes:

```
genes <- c("ENSG00000000003", "ENSG00000000460", "ENSG00000001084")
```

Why do I get incorrect result when selecting the rows by this way:

```
> df[factor(genes), ]
#                    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
# ENSG00000000003 2407 2345 1052 2191 2542  812 3595 4215 1100 5457
# ENSG00000000005    0    5    0    0    1    0    1    0   12    0
# ENSG00000000419 1843 1528 1520 1789 1144 1946 2017 2794 1455 2258
```

and correct by this one: ?

```
> df[as.vector(genes), ]
#                    1    2    3     4    5    6    7    8    9   10
# ENSG00000000003 2407 2345 1052  2191 2542  812 3595 4215 1100 5457
# ENSG00000000460  453  493  884  1180  338  541  606  650  520 3479
# ENSG00000001084 3705 6465 1803 49162 2018 1161 4621 8359 3375 2678
```

Rownames of df are strings, but in another dataframe I have the same names as factors. To have correct results I have to put it into as.vector() all the time.

Can you tell me what is the logic of the first result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`factors` are internally numbers. So when you are trying to subset the dataframe using `factor` it returns you the first 3 results of your dataframe. Check

```
(1:10)[factor(genes)] 
#[1] 1 2 3
```

So here from sequence `1:10` it returns to you first 3 values.

This works for dataframes as well,

```
mtcars[factor(genes), ]
#              mpg cyl disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1
```

If `genes` are rownames of your dataframe you can subset your dataframe directly by doing

```
df[genes, ]
```